# Chrome recently broke copying newlines in textarea set with innerText

Tags: javascript, json, string, html

A while back, I wrote a chrome extension that creates a certain multi-line string of text and copies it to the clipboard, using the hidden textarea and copy command trick. It copied the newlines (/n) as it was supposed to.

But recently, I found out that it's not copying newlines anymore. Just the string mashed together with no line breaks.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `value` on a `<textarea>`, not `innerText`/`innerHTML`. You can also see that a `<textarea>` renders linebreaks as `\n`:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("text").value));
```

```html
<textarea id="text">
Line One
Line Two
Line Three
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspection, when you set a textarea's innerText to a string with newlines, each line of the string becomes its own string, separated by <br> tags, all between the textarea's tags.

To fix it, I had to change it so it sets the textarea's innerHTML to the string instead of using innerText. It now preserves the string as... a string, with line breaks, and it now copies correctly again.

Comment: Should be using `value` on textarea, not innerText or innerHTML

Comment: Oh.. I feel dumb for not thinking of that, because I didn't consider a textarea to be an input with a value attribute.